# How should I interpret for example AA result, when SNPedia only has CC/CT/TT listed?

Tags: genetics, human-genetics, gene

I don't know how to properly formulate this question because I'm new to this, so please edit this if you can...

For example when I would check SNPedia for rs gene, it would have listed CC/CT/TT genes, but my result says AA, so how should I interpret this? I assume it has not been tested, but I want to know for sure, because I have encountered this numerous times already...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to learn about DNA strand orientation: https://www.snpedia.com/index.php/Orientation

Comment: Ah! Thank you! I'm just a beginner at these things. :)